# Remove multiple different suffix from original name

Tags: applescript

I have multiple files which has a same file with a same extension but name but may have multiple different suffix. How do I only remove the suffix? I'm planning to use AppleScript for this as it will be running through Automator.

Eg.
Apple_xh264_xdcamprofile123.mov
Apple_mp4_prores321.mov
Apple_xh265_prores456.mov

How do i remove the suffix be it any file name containing those suffix and retain only the name and extension.

Result expected.
Apple_xh264.mov
Apple_mp4.mov
Apple_xh265.mov

Answer (score 0):

You can look for the divider characters from the end of the string (the last occurrence), and use the offsets to build a new name:

```
set input to {"Apple_xh264_xdcamprofile123.mov", "Apple_mp4_prores321.mov", "Apple_xh265_prores456.mov"}
set output to {}

repeat with anItem in the input
  set reversed to (reverse of items of anItem as text) -- search from end
  if (offset of "_" in reversed) is 0 then -- suffix marker not found
    set end of output to anItem
  else
    set extension to text -1 thru -(offset of "." in reversed) of anItem
    set newName to text 1 thru -((offset of "_" in reversed) + 1) of anItem
    set end of the output to newName & extension
  end if
end repeat
return output
```

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, however just to let you know that the main name is always changing. It's not always the same, however the suffix is always the same but there are a few of them.

So the expected result here is actually creating 1 automator to receive any file name with any suffix in it and be able to remove them, in that case I will not need to create individual automator app for individual suffix. Apologies for not being clear earlier.

Comment: Both scripts (red_menace and mine) are keeping: the suffix (last chars after the '.') and the beginning of the name (any group of chars with one '_' in middle). Only the chars in between are deleted. in the format xxxx_yyyyy_zzzz.eee, both scripts do not care about content and length of the xxxx and yyyy. it could be anything. If you are doing the loop through all files in automator, then use variable input to get current file name and output to send back updated name. is it clear enough ?

Answer (score 0):

An other suggestion is to use Applescript text item delimiters.

Your string seems to be always xxxx_yyyy_zzzz.eee (length of each group does not matter !).

You can use text item delimiters "." and "_" and then delete only the 3rd part of the text ("zzzz"). That's what the handler CleanName does in script bellow :

```
set myList to {"Apple_xh264_xdcamprofile123.mov", "Apple_mp4_prores321.mov", "Apple_xh265_prores456.mov"}
set myOutput to {}
repeat with anItem in myList
    set newName to CleanedName(anItem)
    log newName
end repeat
return myOutput


on CleanedName(localOld) -- convert xxxx_yyyy_zzzz.eee into xxxx_yyyy.ee
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {".", "_"}
    try
        set localNew to (text item 1 of localOld) & "_" & (text item 2 of localOld) & "." & (text item 4 of localOld)
    on error
        set localNew to ""
    end try
    return localNew
end CleanedName
```

The Try block is in case some of your file names are not following the expected format.
You can use CleanedName directly in your Automator loop going through all files

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, however just to let you know that the main name is always changing. It's not always the same, however the suffix is always the same but there are a few of them.

Comment: So the expected result here is actually creating 1 automator  to receive any file name with any suffix in it and be able to remove them, in that case I will not need to create individual automator app for individual suffix.

Apologies for not being clear earlier.